# For what value of $m$ the is sum $\sum_{i = 0}^{m} {10 \choose i}{20 \choose m - i}$ where ${p\choose q} = 0$, if $p<q$, a maximum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-theorem

For what value of $m$ the is sum

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{m} {10 \choose i}{20 \choose m - i}\text{where ${p\choose q}$} = 0\text{, if $p<q$, a maximum}$$

**My approach**

$$\sum_i^{m} {10 \choose i}{20 \choose m - i} = {10 \choose 0}{20 \choose m} + {10 \choose 1}{20 \choose m - 1} + \dots + {10 \choose m}{20 \choose 0}$$

$$(1 +x)^{20} = {20 \choose 0} + {20 \choose 1}x + \dots + {20 \choose m-1}x^{m-1} + {20 \choose m}x^{m} + \dots + {20 \choose 20}x^{20}$$

$$(1 +x)^{10} = {10 \choose 0} + {10 \choose 1}x + \dots + {10 \choose 10}x^{10}$$

**Later what to do??**
Any other method or hint will be greatly welcomed.

Comment: More generally I wonder if there's a way to find the maximum where we don't fix 10 and 20, so finding the maximum of $\sum{A \choose i}{B \choose m-i}$

Comment: By [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), the sum is equal to $\binom{30}{m}$ whose maximum is at $m=15$.

Comment: @MatthewEngelstein: that is a separate question, but using Vandermonde, we get that sum to be $\binom{A+B}{m}$, whose maximum is at $m=\frac{A+B}2$ (if $A+B$ is even) or $m=\frac{A+B\pm1}2$ (if $A+B$ is odd).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) says that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{10}{i}\binom{20}{m-i}=\binom{30}{m}\tag1
$$
The central binomial coefficient is the greatest. Therefore, the maximum of $(1)$ is when $m=15$; that is, $\binom{30}{15}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'm gonna to approach it. Hopefully, it'll give some intuition into the Vandermonde identity that you can read up on later.

Consider a jar of $r$ red marbles and $b$ blue marbles. We need to find the number of ways to pick $m$ marbles.

Well we can pick $1$ red and $m - 1$ blue marbles or $2$ red and $m - 2$ blue marbles or $3$ red and $m - 3$ and so forth...

We need to find the sum total of the number of ways to pick $i$ red and $m - i$ blue marbles, which is exactly the RHS of:
$$ {r+b \choose m} = \sum_i^m {r \choose i}{b \choose m - i}$$

And the LHS is exactly as we described previously: the number of ways to choose $m$ marbles from all $r + b$ marbles. Does this make sense? We are essentially a combinatorial trick called *"counting by two ways"*.

Now where does ${r+b \choose m}$ achieve its maximum? Well Pascal's triangle has it's maximums of every row down it's center column, so ${r+b \choose m}$ is maximized at $\left\lfloor {\frac{r+b}{2}}\right\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x)^{10}= 10_{C_{0}}+10_{C_{1}} x+\cdots+10_{C_{10}} x^{10} \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots .(1)$$
$$(1+x)^{20}= 20_{C_{20}}x^{20}+20_{C_{19}} x^{19}+\cdots+20_{C_{0}} \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots .(2)$$
On multiplying these two...
$$(1+x)^ {30}= (\cdots)x^{30}+(\cdots)x^{29}+\cdots$$
The largest coefficient would be that of $x^{15}$ and that would be equal to ...
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m}\left(\begin{array}{l}10 \\ i\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}20 \\ 15-i\end{array}\right),$$
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write the (3) expansion as $$(1+1/x)^{10}=~^{10}C_0 + ~^{10}C_1 (1/x)+ ~^{10}C_2(1/x^2)+......+ ~^{10}C_n(1/x^{10})~~~~~(3)$$
Now multiply (2) and (3) mainly collecting the  terms independent of $x$ in the product $$S=\text{coefficient of $x^0$ in} (1+x)^{20}(1+1/x)^{10}$$